# Constructor in private section

Tags: c++, constructor

What is the use of declaring constructors in private section in C++?
We can declare friend functions and constructors in private section but what is the use?

Comment: One case is to disable object being created on stack.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare the constructor as `private`, nobody but the class itself can create a new instance of it. Most likely, there is a static method returning a class instance instead. This grants some control about the amount of instances that exist in a given program.

The [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) is one application of this practice. By using a private constructor and some other tricks, you can make sure that only a single instance of this class exists, because the user cannot just create a `new` instance on his own.

Answer (score 0):

There are many scenarios for having private constructors.

Eg:

- Restricting object creation
- For singleton patterns
- Restricting certain type of constructor (e.g. copy constructor, default constructor)

Private constructor means a user can not directly instantiate a class. Instead, you can create objects, where you have static class functions that can create and return instances of a class.

Another use is to [prevent inheritance of your class](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/final-classes.html), since derived classes won't be able to access your class' constructor. Of course, in this situation you still need a function that creates instances of the class.

Also it is commonly used in the Singleton pattern where the object is accessed through a static member function, Otherwise everyone can create an instance of your class, so it's not a singleton any more. For a singleton by definition there can exist only one instance.

Answer (score 0):

E.g. by making constructor private,  you can control the constructions of objects.  Maybe you want that only n instances of your object are existing at the same time.  You can create a function that counts this.  See also Singleton pattern